# Welches Verb ist formeller, um auszudrücken, dass man das Rauchen aufgibt bzw. einstellt?

Tags: verb-usage, formality, verb-choice

> 1. Ich gebe das Rauchen auf.
> 2. Ich stelle das Rauchen ein.

Verwendet man öfters das Verb *aufgeben* anstatt *einstellen*? Und ist *einstellen* formeller als *aufgeben*?

Comment: Ich würde sagen, *aufgeben* meint für immer, während *einstellen* temporär gemeint sein kann, z.B. "In Anwesenheit von Kindern oder Schwangeren stelle ich das Rauchen ein."

Comment: @Ingo Ich würde sagen, mach das zu einer Antwort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Etwas aufgeben* bedeutet, dass man etwas für immer (oder zumindest für eine sehr lange Zeit) nicht mehr tut/versucht/… Es ist dabei irrelevant, ob es funktioniert, es zählt der Gedanke (man kann nicht in die Zukunft sehen).

> Morgen gebe ich das Rauchen auf.
>   Die Maschine lässt sich einfach nicht bauen. Ich gebe die Idee auf.

*Etwas einstellen* bedeutet, dass man eine gewisse Tätigkeit eine gewisse Zeit lang nicht durchführt. Über die Zeit danach wird nichts ausgesagt. Im Gegensatz zu *aufgeben,* das immer eine eigene, getroffene Entscheidung ist, kann *einstellen* auch äußeren Umständen geschuldet sein (siehe Beispiele).

> Ich werde das Rauchen während der Zugfahrt einstellen müssen. Hoffentlich habe ich genug Nikotinpflaster dabei.
>   Wenn der Herr Professor kommt, stellen Sie bitte die unanständigen Kommentare ein.

Answer (score -1):

Die zwei Sätze bedeuten etwas Unterschiedliches.

> Ich gebe das Rauchen auf.

*Ich gebe es auf. Ich werde niemals wieder rauchen.* (guter Vorsatz!)

> Ich stelle das Rauchen ein.

*Stellen Sie bitte das Rauchen ein.* (früher Standardansage im Flugzeug bei Start und Landung. Danach wird die nächste Fluppe angezündet.)

Comment: "Das Rauchen einstellen" mit "Das Rauchen einstellen" zu erklären, ist irgendwie lustig. Wie wär's mit sowas wie "Das Rauchen für den Moment beenden/unterbrechen"?

Comment: Den Beispielsatz kann man ergooglen und kommt da auf hunderte identische Treffer, was damit gemeint ist. Zusammen mit dem durch Erklärung bekannten Gegensatz darüber ist das besser als jede ableitende Erklärung.

Comment: @Janka: Bitte ergänze Deine Frage um die entsprechenden Informationen. Es sollte nicht nötig sein, dass jemand irgendetwas googeln muss, um Deine Antwort zu verstehen, insbesondere wenn darauf noch nicht einmal hingewiesen wird. Idealerweise findest Du bei Google diese Antwort und darin alles, was bezügliche dieser Frage wichtig ist.

Comment: Lieber Wrzlprmft, meine Antwort kann man auch ohne Ergooglen von irgendetwas verstehen. Aber wenn man sich immer noch im Unklaren darüber ist, was "Stellen Sie bitte das Rauchen ein." heißt und einem auch "früher Standardansage im Flugzeug bei Start und Landung" nicht weiterhilft, dann sollte man das vielleicht wirklich ergooglen. Es ist mir leider nicht möglich, die entsprechenden Videos hier einzukleben.